# ReactJS - Wait third party script response before render

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, reactjs

I implemented [J-Toker](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker) in my frontend app using React and flow (with a Rails API backend), in a similar way to this project [react-flux-jwt-authentication-sample](https://github.com/auth0/react-flux-jwt-authentication-sample/tree/gh-pages/src)

The dashboard should only be accessed by logged in user. In order to do this, J-Toker calls my Rails API and return the loggedIn User (or not if no one is loggedIn...) that is accessible using `Auth.user`.

So I have my Dashboard component wrapped in an AuthenticatedComponent:

**Dashobard.jsx**

```
export default AuthenticatedComponent(Dashobard);
```

Here is my **AuthenticatedComponent.jsx**:

```
export default (ComposedComponent) => {
  return class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    static willTransitionTo(transition) {
      if (!LoginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
        transition.redirect('/login', {}, {'nextPath' : transition.path});
      }
    }

  ...
}
```

Finally here is my **LoginStore.jsx** code:

```
import Auth from 'j-toker';

class LoginStore extends BaseStore {

  ...

  isLoggedIn() {
    return Auth.user.signedIn;
  }
}
```

Everything works great except when I manually refresh the page. In this case, the Auth.user.signedIn return `undefined` even if the user is logged in and is redirected to the login page. I found that the problem comes from the fact that `Auth.user` is not yet loaded when `LoginStore.isLoggedIn()` is called because in this case `Auth.user` returns an empty object and if I wait a little (tested with a basic `setTimeout`) it returns the loggedIn user.

I am new to React.JS (using it for just a week now) and I'm not sure how to deal with this. I read A LOT of articles and cannot understand yet how React.JS is meant to be used, espacially with third party plugins (I also have a lot of problems using animation plugins but it's another story...).

Could someone help me on this?

It would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you pass the configuration to J-Toker, the library will check for a stored token. In case it finds one it will validate the token with you API. This is why calling configure, it will return you a jquery Deferred object, which will be resolved after the validation has been done or rejected if there is no stored token. If the validation passes in you API the user object will be returned and set in Auth.user.

By following your example project you can fix this by rendering the component after the Deferred has been resolved.

```
var promise = Auth.configure({
  apiUrl: 'your-api-host'
});

promise.always(function() {
  router.run(function (Handler) {
   React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('content'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I cannot test this right now as I switched this project to Angular. But I'll try it as soon as possible and I'll let you know